# jQuery Cycle2 Change number of slideshow elements by resizing window

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-cycle, responsive-slides

I'm building a responsive design for both desktop and tablet view. In this design I'm using one or more slideshow build with [jQuery Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/). This slideshows containts in the desktop 3 objects in a slider and in the tablet version just 2.

**My approach:** I'm checking for a window resize event, unwrap all cycle captions, wrap the new ones around the given number of elements and reinit the cycle plugin.

**My problem:** Everything works fine till I'm trying to reinit the cycle plugin. It just don't work without any failure or something. So just the reinit seems to be the problem.

**My code:**

```
//function to fire the resize event when its done
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

$(window).resize(function() {
    delay(function(){
        if( window.innerWidth <= 979 ){
            resizeWrapper( 2 );
        }
    }, 500);
});

//function for delete wrappers and wrap new ones based on a given number
function resizeWrapper( numberOfItems ){
    $( '.productsItem' ).unwrap();

    var $set_latestProductsCycle = $( '#latestProductsCycle' ).children();
    for( var i=0, len = $set_latestProductsCycle.length; i < len; i+=numberOfItems ){
        $set_latestProductsCycle.slice( i, i+numberOfItems ).wrapAll( '<div class="popularProductsWrapper"/>' );
    }
    $( '#latestProductsCycle' ).cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        prev: '#latestProductsButtonLeft',
        next: '#latestProductsButtonRight',
        timeout: 0,
        caption: '.popularProductsWrapper'
    });
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question by myself:

I forgot to remove the sentinel container, which will be created, when you first call the cycle script. Furthermore when I reinit the cycle container it's not necessary to define a "caption".

In short the function should look like this:

```
    function resizeWrapper( cycleContainer, numberOfItems ){
    $( cycleContainer ).cycle( 'destroy' );
    $( cycleContainer + ' .cycle-sentinel' ).remove();

    $( cycleContainer + ' .slider .item' ).unwrap();

    var $set_latestProductsCycle = $( cycleContainer ).children();

    for( var i=0, len = $set_latestProductsCycle.length; i < len; i+=numberOfItems ){
        $set_latestProductsCycle.slice( i, i+numberOfItems ).wrapAll( '<div class="slider"/>' );
    }

    $( cycleContainer ).cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        prev: cycleContainer + 'Prev',
        next: cycleContainer + 'Next',
        timeout: 0
    });
}
```

Thanks for everybodies attention.